# Kotlin-Flow When there is no value to emit what happens

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

For example we have a flow that emits 3 integer in it. Than a collector collects it from a viewModel. Finally, the collector collected 3 integer and will never collect a new value from flow because we just emitted 3 integer. What happens to the flow after that? Is it going to be cancelled or it will survive ? If it will survive does it cause memmory problems? If not should I cancel it on my own

**Random Place**

```
fun integerFLow() = flow<Int> {
    emit(1)
    emit(2)
    emit(3)
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        integerFlow().collect { int ->
            println("integer: $int")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After collecting 3 items, flow is completed and the collector stops collecting (`collect()` function returns).

Comment: When collect() function returns does the flow still occupy memmory? I mean should I cancel the scope? Do I need to handle anything? @broot

Comment: No, in the above case it will all clean up by itself.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it from stopping emmissions?